# Problems removing unique constraint postgresql

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I made a mistake in setting my primary key on a table, say on field 'x'. An other field, say field 'y' I placed an unique constraint and to this field some other tables referenced as foreign key.

I noticed my mistake and dropped the primary key on field 'x' and placed it on 'y'. At this point I realized I could remove the unique constraint on 'y'. But now I get errors in doing so, telling me: cannot drop constraint 'y'_unique_constraint on table 'foo' because other objects depend on it.

I tried by doing a transaction and a 'set constraints all deffered' but that didn't help.

How can I remove this constraint without building my database from scratch? As far as I can see this unique constraint on 'y' is redundant now the primary key is on the same field.

Comment: Well it appears there are still foreign keys from other tables referring to the unique 'x' column. A foreign key **requires** the referred column(set) to be unique.

Comment: No, that's not the case, it seems that the foreign keys are referenced to the unique constraint index instead of the field it self: ...depends on index 'y'_unique_constraint. So I need to 'tell' the foreign keys somehow to reference to the newly created primary key.

Comment: You cannot _tell_ something to the foreign key constraints. Just drop the old ones and create the new ones.

Comment: I hoped there would be a faster way but yes, I think that would be the solution.

Comment: Have you tried dropping it with `CASCADE`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html (the depending object of a contraint is its index)

Comment: That is what I've done now, now I have to re-add the foreign keys, but that is not such a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize at first that the foreign keys are referencing a index rather than a field. So by creating a new primary key on the same field didn't mean that the foreign keys switched to the new index.

I now dropped the unique constraint using cascade and re-added all the foreign keys, they are now using the primary key.

Comment: Foreign keys do reference **columns**, not an index. But to reference a column that column must be unique. Either through a unique constraint or a primary key constraint - both are in turn enforced by a unique index